# Pass null parameters to crexport (Crystal Reports)

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there anyway to call ***crexport.exe*** (Crystal Reports Commandline Exporter) passing `null` parameters?

My .rpt file has two parameters, one of them is optional.

Everytime I try to call `crexport -U (...) -a "Param1:test"` ignoring param2 (optional) I get a missing parameters error.

Comment: I don't think `null` will be accepted, instead try to pass either `0` or `NA` if parameter is not used

Comment: Yeah, I had to create an workaround... since the parameter was a date, every date with the year=1700 would be handled as a null date in Crystal programmatically. My company didn't exist in middle age... so, it's not a problem to do that.